# How do i get an object from another class in java

Tags: java, oop, object

i have an object for example called myObject and this object has an integer which is 5. How would i send this object to another class or retrieve the object from its class it was created in so i can use the object and all its values even though i created in a different class?

the class myObject was created from

```
public class Class
{
    int Int;
    public void setInt(i)
    {
      Int = i;
    }
}
```

how would i send the object below to another class where i can use it and have access to all its values etc.

```
Class myObject = new Class();
myObject.setInt(5);
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a `getInt` method that returns the variable `Int`?

Comment: The answer really depends. What are your previous programming experiences?  As it stands, the question is too broad.

Comment: i want to get the whole object not just one value

Comment: An `int` isn't an `Object` it's a `primitive`, therefore can only be retrieve by value.

Comment: Then there is "myObject" of type Class (Class is a very unfortunately named class).  @PatrickJAbareII Yes, but OP does not need that distinction here, nor right now.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. Otherwise it will get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should be more specific. Having an int named 'Int' and class named 'Class' can get very confusing.

Your second class is going to need to take the first class as a value in the constructor, unless you're going to make everything in the first class visible to everything in the package or the project (which I wouldn't recommend doing). Therefore, we need a public getter and setter for the int value in the original class (now named TestObject; and the int now called num), because I made the variable private (visible only to the class). Now that the getters and setters are created, the second class (now named TestObject2) can call the getter from TestObject to retrieve the int value.

It's kind of counterproductive to have a getter for the value in TestObject, but I just included it to show you how to get the value.

If you have any questions let me know! I put the code below:

```
public class TestObject{
    private int num;

    public int getInt(){
        return num;
    }

    public void setInt(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        TestObject obj = new TestObject();
        obj.setInt(5);
        TestObject2 obj2 = new TestObject2(obj);
        System.out.println(obj2.getTestObjectNum());
    }
}



public class TestObject2 {
    TestObject testObject;

    public TestObject2(TestObject testObject){
        this.testObject = testObject;
    }

    int getTestObjectNum(){
        return testObject.getInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

define the class so your class would recognize it then call it from within the class like this:

```
newClass = new Class();
newClass.setInt(x);
```

if it is in another package i believe it is something like this:

```
newClass = new packageName.Class();
newClass.setInt(x);
```

this is exactly how imports work, you define the class by "import javax.swing.JFrame;
then call anything inside that class by defining an object like "JFrame f = new JFrame();
then you call the methods inside the JFrame class by doing "f.add();"

Comment: I really don't think this is what OP is asking for.